# Zealous image editing

Tags: discussion, editing

I've noticed recently that a user has gone through all of my posts and resized the images.

While I don't think it harmed (most) of the posts, it seems unnecessary, especially since [this update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189343/images-should-be-automatically-rescaled-and-the-full-size-linked-or-put-into-a-l).

Is this **encouraged** or should they be asked to refrain from doing it in future?

- [How can I remove the cork from a wine bottle when I don't have a corkscrew?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/how-can-i-remove-the-cork-from-a-wine-bottle-when-i-dont-have-a-corkscrew/1551#1551)
- [How can I prevent the bin bag falling into the bin?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1657/how-can-i-prevent-the-bin-bag-falling-into-the-bin/6352#6352)
- [What is a good way to organise and identify keys on a keyring?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9614/what-is-a-good-way-to-organise-and-identify-keys-on-a-keyring/9630#9630)
- [Preventing socks from leaving marks on skin](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/preventing-socks-from-leaving-marks-on-skin/9800#9800)
- [How to move heavy (~50kg) bulky (~1m cubed) items a short (1km) distance?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/how-to-move-heavy-50kg-bulky-1m-cubed-items-a-short-1km-distance/9698#9698)
- [How can I make an improvised vegetable steamer?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6158/how-can-i-make-an-improvised-vegetable-steamer/6159#6159)
- [What is the best way to tumble-dry wet sneakers?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/132/what-is-the-best-way-to-tumble-dry-wet-sneakers/1674#1674)
- [How can I charge a single rechargeable battery?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/2277/47)
- [How can I make an improvised vegetable steamer?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/6158/47) (Q)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Use medium images linked to the original resolution image.

Using the medium size image is preferred unless a high amount of detail is required. The editor did well since they also linked the image to the original resolution image. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262235/202832) on Meta SE and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/1234256) on Meta Stack Overflow provide more details about image resizing.

Comment: `Using the medium size image is preferred` - preferred by whom?  Has this been discussed before? I've not seen this practice on other SEs.

Comment: @JamesWebster The practice to use reasonably-sized images has been preferred my many editors, however, I do not see any documented questions on the subject.

Comment: I found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189343/images-should-be-automatically-rescaled-and-the-full-size-linked-or-put-into-a-l). I would suggest that images be left alone, as they are handled automatically now!